# Creating a parent ID cell in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I've got a spreadsheet of various categories and I'd like to create a column which gets the parent name of that particular category.

They are currently broken down as follows:

```
01.01 Category 1
01.02 Category 1a
01.02.01 Category 1aa
01.02.02 Category 1ab
01.02.03 Category 1ac
01.03 Category 1c
```

I've put the numbers into a seperate column using `=LEFT(A2,(FIND(" ",A2,1)-1))`

and I've put the names of the categories into another column using `=MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2)+1,256)`

but I've not managed to get the parent name into a  column yet so was hoping someone could help.

Comment: Sure, i've uploaded it to: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wgj7pkp5rkt1ms4/test.csv?dl=0

it's the parent ID and Parent Name columns i'm trying to create!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **B2:** **`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(LEFT(A2:A, (FIND(" ", A2:A, 1)-1)), ))`**
- **C2:** **`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(MID(A2:A, FIND(" ", A2:A)+1, 256), ))`**
- **D2:** **`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(RIGHT(B2:B, LEN(B2:B)-3), ))`**
- **E2:** **`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(LEN(B2:B)>3, LEFT(B2:B, 5), ), ))`**
- **F2:** **`=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(
        IFERROR(IF(LEN(B2:B)>3, LEFT(B2:B, 5), ), ),
       {IFERROR(IF(LEN(B2:B)>3, LEFT(B2:B, 5), ), ), 
        IFERROR(MID(A2:A, FIND(" ", A2:A)+1, 256), )}, 2, 0), ))`**

[image]

Comment: Brilliant thanks, i managed to get the sub id and parent id last night but the parent name bit was really baffling me.